# Mejorar velocidad de carga de sistema web en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buen dia compañeros, les comento que en la empresa donde laburo hay un sistema que cada tabla tiene aproximadamente 50 mil datos, este sistema hecho en laravel 5.6, y usa PHP 5.6, muestra esos datos en vistas que si tienen paginacion, no muestra imagenes. La consulta para obtener esos datos es de la siguiente forma:

```
$model = LogErrorTransaction::leftJoin('metadata_culqi','log_error_transaction.code_metadata','=','metadata_culqi.code_metadata');
    
    if(isset($search)){
        $model->where('log_error_transaction.nombre_cliente','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('log_error_transaction.apellidos_cliente','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('log_error_transaction.email_cliente','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('log_error_transaction.monto','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('log_error_transaction.navegador','like','%'.$search.'%');
    }

    $model->select(
        'log_error_transaction.nombre_cliente',
        'log_error_transaction.apellidos_cliente',
        'log_error_transaction.email_cliente',
        'log_error_transaction.trama_respuesta_culqi',
        'log_error_transaction.token',
        'log_error_transaction.monto',
        'log_error_transaction.navegador',
        'log_error_transaction.version',
        'log_error_transaction.estado',
        'log_error_transaction.action',
        'log_error_transaction.created_at',
        'metadata_culqi.metadata',
        'metadata_culqi.code_metadata'
    );

    if (@$column) {
        $model = $model->orderBy($column, $order);
    }
    $model = $model->orderBy('log_error_transaction.id','DESC')->paginate($pager);
    return $model;
```

El detalle es que esa vista se demora en cargar, incluso hay veces que demora mas de 3 minutos.
Les agradecería si saben formas de poder mejorar la velocidad de carga de esta.

Comment: Que valor contiene `$pager`? Ya que esto es la cantidad de datos a cargar. Por otro lado, utilizas algo para la paginacion? como datatables o simplemente el paginate de laravel

Comment: @JuanRivera antes el $pager tenia como valor 100, pero lo baje a 10 para no traer tantos datos, si simplemente se esta usando el paginate de laravel

Comment: Podrías utilizar Server Side Processing con el paquete de [Yajra\DataTables](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/). Este me ha servido para casos similares al tuyo. Pero tendrás que adaptar tu vista y el query de consulta.

Comment: @Barbatos ya integre datatables, pero siento que igual demora en la carga y si puse serverSide:true, incluso demora mas que tenerlo en false porque si esta en false, carga toda la data y puedo ir cambiando segun la paginacion, en cambio si es true cada vez que cambio de pagina hace una peticion.

Comment: Pero esa es la idea del server side: devolver solo la cantidad de registros deseados. Lo otro que se me ocurre es crear índices de búsqueda sobre las columnas que intervienen en la clausura where de tu consulta, creo ayudaría en el rendimiento de la query.

Comment: Yo veo que mas que laravel es una falta de eficiencia en la consulta. ¿Tienes índices bien creados? ¿Por qué no usas full text en lugar de los likes?

Comment: @ManuelRobles aunque la condición no permita entrar al uso de los liks igual demora en la carga, el tema de que el sistema este hecho en Laravel 5.4 usando PHP 5.6, afecta también?